# How can "find" check return code?

Tags: macos, shell

```
find . -iname '*.rar' -execdir unar {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

How can I modify command above in order to remove archive only if unar returned successful return code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to; `-execdir` already acts like a normal predicate, succeeding or failing depending on the result of the command executed.